# cocos2d for iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a rectangular shape like a bar,  i want it to be hanged and swinging in both direction continuously (a bomb is thrown in may game and this is opening and closing the path) 
how can i implement this in cocos2d space manager also how can i make a similar bar rotating around its center (a center as a pivot point)

Comment: Are you doing this with Box2D?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CCActionMoveBy` or `CCActionMoveTo` for moving one side to another the `CCSprite` and `CCActionRotateTo` or `CCActionRotateBy` to rotate (in case you don't want it to collide using Box2D or Chimpunk).